# What is the vector notation for $ \epsilon^{ijk} a_i b_j c_k $?

Tags: tensors

If we use [Einstein summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) notation the upper indices and the lower indices match - then we do summation:

$$ a \cdot b = \langle a | b \rangle = a^i b_i := \sum a^i b_i  $$

In the example I'm looking at there is a symbol called $\epsilon^{ijk}$ which is antisymmetric in the indices $i\leftrightarrow j \leftrightarrow k$.  What is the vector notation for 
$$ \epsilon^{ijk} a_i b_j c_k  \stackrel{?}{=} a \cdot (b \times c)$$
At least if we write it this way, it's clear there's anti-symmetry between $(a,b,c)$. Is this a short-hand for $3 \times 3$ [determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) or the vector [triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product)?

Comment: @ThePirateBay The same reason why other questions have upvotes? Because someone approves of their post?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Three_dimensions_2 ... read this ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan “What is the vector notation for…” I believe. I think that cactus314 chose to put the question mark above the equals sign.

Comment: @ThePirateBay That remark is not constructive; it implies that this post does not deserve its (first) upvote. If you disapprove of a user’s post, then explain why and suggest ways to improve it. It would also be good to invoke meta posts, such as [how to ask a good question](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) in order to substantiate your comment and to make sure you’re validated to complain about someone else. Please uphold the [be nice policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240839) in the future.

Comment: I still don't understand the question. The OP already indicates that they're familiar with two notations for this operation. So what is the remaining question? I also don't understand the question mark because it seems like the OP already knows that these two things are equal.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor. Oh, I didn't want to insult the op or to underestimate their question, I was just wondering how is it possible that a post got an upvote one second after it appeared in the new posts stream. It took me about 20 seconds to read the entire question, so I was just surprised how fast someone can read, udnerstand and decide to upvote. I'm right now saying sorry to OP is I insulted them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check: http://internal.physics.uwa.edu.au/~styler/teaching/CM/index.pdf

(2.21)

It is:

$$a\cdot(b\times c)\left(=\det(a,b,c)\right)$$